# Laravel 5 curl is getting data from the wrong db

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have two Laravel applications in my machine.

One is an API which has the following code and uses the **API database**:

```php
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
     // return the database name
     return response(Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default').'.database'));
 }
```

And the other is the client app which sends requests using curl and it uses the **Client database**:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
$result['content'] = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem is that when sending the curl request (from the **client app**), instead of getting the name of the **API database** I get the name of the **Client database** like if it was sending the request but then just using its local db, why would this happen?

This doesn't happen when i use a browser to send the request in which case it works correctly (i get the **API database** name), it just happens with curl

Comment: hey were you able to solve this?

Comment: have you solve it? I also faced the same issue